# Replace a column in file with look up table from another file

Tags: awk, sed, python

I have a tab delimited file with a column that has multiple values separated by comma where i wanted to replace values from a look up table

Lookup_file:

```
  ID    Name
g_00001 g_00001
g_00002 cytA
g_00003 g_00003
g_00004 mntB
g_00005 recF
g_00006 gyaN
g_00007 traR
g_00008 g_00008
g_00009 g_00009
g_00010 hypE
```

input_file:

```
Name    Start   Stop    Strand  Number of Genes Genes
op00001 1544    5454    +   2   cytA, g_00001
op00002 7026    12012   +   2   recF, mntB
op00003 15215   16854   -   3   g_00010,cytA, g_00009
op00004 19856   25454   -   2   hypE, g_00020
op00005 20791   23568   +   2   gyaN, g_00005
```

Output file:

```
Name    Start   Stop    Strand  Number of Genes Genes
op00001 1544    5454    +   2   g_00002, g_00001
op00002 7026    12012   +   2   g_00005, g_00004
op00003 15215   16854   -   3   g_00010, g_00002, g_00009
op00004 19856   25454   -   2   g_00010, g_00020
op00005 20791   23568   +   2   g_00006, g_00005
```

Based on some examples here , i have tried the following code

```
awk -F';' 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=$1;next}{$6=a[$1]}1' lookup input
```

and its not changing anything.

Another way is by trying one by one using sed -i 's/cytA/g_00002/' and create sed files for each line and run it in loop is what i thought of but i wanted to check if there is better way of doing it.

Comment: You're setting the field separator to `;` but there are no `;`s in your input and in fact you said your fields are tab-delimited so try `-F'\t'` instead of `-F';'` then let us know if you still have a problem. Don't do that sed in a loop thing you mention.

Comment: My apologies, i should have double checked before posting. I actually modified the separator to tab and tested on my dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those "multiple values separated by comma" are separated by comma and (in most but not all of the cases) spaces which doesn't make it easier to handle them. Try adapting the field separator and operating on every gene as a single field:

```
awk -F"[, \t]*" '
NR==FNR         {a[$2] = $1
                 next
                }
                {for (i=6; i<=NF; i++)  if ($i in a) sub($i, a[$i])
                }
1
' OFS="\t" Lookup_file input_file
Name    Start   Stop    Strand  Number of Genes Genes
op00001 1544    5454    +   2   g_00002, g_00001
op00002 7026    12012   +   2   g_00005, g_00004
op00003 15215   16854   -   3   g_00010,g_00002, g_00009
op00004 19856   25454   -   2   g_00010, g_00020
op00005 20791   23568   +   2   g_00006, g_00005
```

Comment: thank you. this worked beautifully. "awk -F"[, \t]*" - What does * represent here? Also how does "1" on 7th line is used as part of logic?

Comment: A * in a regex pattern means: "repeat pattern 0 to many times", so e.g. several spaces separate two fields. The "1" is a "pattern" that evaluates to "TRUE" and the following empty action defaults to "{print}".

Comment: That would fail if the string being replaced was a substring of another string earlier in the line (given `a b` in the lookup file and `abc,b` in the input file it'll output `aac,b` instead of `abc,a`), or if a replacement string earlier in the line could also be string to be replaced later in  the line (given `a b` and `c a` in the lookup file and `b,a` in the input file it'll output `c,a` instead of `a,c`). It'd also fail if any of the strings could contain regexp or backreference metacharacters but that seems unlikely given  the sample input.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
NR == FNR {
    map[$2] = $1
    next
}
{
    n = split($NF,g,/[[:space:]]*,[[:space:]]*/)
    out = ""
    for ( i=1; i<=n; i++ ) {
        out = (i>1 ? out ", " : "") (g[i] in map ? map[g[i]] : g[i])
    }
    $NF = out
    print
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk lookup_file input_file
Name    Start   Stop    Strand  Number of Genes Genes
op00001 1544    5454    +       2       g_00002, g_00001
op00002 7026    12012   +       2       g_00005, g_00004
op00003 15215   16854   -       3       g_00010, g_00002, g_00009
op00004 19856   25454   -       2       g_00010, g_00020
op00005 20791   23568   +       2       g_00006, g_00005
```

Comment: thank you for your response. this worked for me as well !